# How to directly open Jupyter from cmd instead of copying link

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I often use jupyter for classes, and use the commmand `python -m notebook` to open the notebook. The tab that opens up shows an error, and then I have to copy one of the links in the terminal window instead. Is there a way or a command that I can use so that one of those links automatically opens up?

[image]

NOTE: It opens the file location (first address in the picture) and fails, and I use the links below to open jupyter. I want the terminal to open the links directly if possible to save time.

[image]

This is the error that I get.

Comment: Another NOTE: I installed jupyter using pip and not through the anaconda package.

Comment: Can you please share more information about the error?

Comment: It just says file not found

Answer (score 1):

```
jupyter notebook notebook.ipynb
```

Taken from [this](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html) documentation.

It shouldn't matter whether you install it using conda or pip.

Or you can just type `jupyter notebook` which should open up a your file directory in the browser and let you navigate to the notebook file you want to open.

Edit: For this error, it really is hard without knowing the full context of the commands you are running, the directory you are calling from, and where this file you want to open is located. Make sure you are in the folder that contains your notebook file. If not, you should specify the entire path to the notebook file. Finally, does the command `jupyter notebook` by itself work?

Comment: It does the same thing for me. The same error: File not found, and then I have to use the links below

Comment: @NikitParakh Could you verify if your Jupyter notebook exists?

Comment: It does exist, yes

Comment: Try adding jupyter notebook to your PATH variable.

Comment: Is there a command for that? Or do I have to do that using "edit system variables"?

Comment: There is a way you can do it from your command prompt, but I would recommend just doing it through "edit the system environment variables"  UI through the control panel.

Comment: I added it to path, but still the same issue: File Not Found

Comment: Can you show what the entire error is regarding file not found? What file is not found?

Comment: Adding it to the question